# How to access the main DataContext from within a template

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

### Summary

I've got an element within a data template, that I want bound to some property of the main data context.
I realise that in this specific situation, a different solution may be preferable (and I have a working solution that avoids this), but I suspect this kind of problem may come up again and I want to know how to solve it in the general case.

Below are the specifics of my situation.

### The Details

**Data Hierarchy**: I have a list of type `A`, each instance of `A` has a list of type `B`, each instance of `B` has some other data including a `string` for a text log.

**UI Structure**: I have a `ComboBox` to select an item of type `A`. I have a `TabControl` with the tabs representing items of type `B`, taken from the selected `A` above. In each tab, there is a means to enter data to populate the object of type `B`, and a log, representing changes to that instance of `B`.

**Backing Logic**: I track the selected item in each list with properties (`SelectionA` and `SelectionB` in the data context, `MainWindowViewModel`) that notify when they change. The `B` object also notifies when its log text changes. These ensure that the UI responds to changes to the backing data.

**Problem**: I want to move the notify logic to all be in one place (the `DataContext`, i.e. `MainWindowViewModel`), rather than having some in the `B` class and needing to duplicate the notify logic. To achieve this, I add a property (`SelectionBLogText`) to track the `LogText` property of the `SelectionB` object, and bind the log (in the templated tabpanel) to the main `SelectionBLogText` property. The problem is that within the tabpage, I can only seem to bind to properties of the selected `B` object (from the selected tab), and I need to bind to a property of the `DataContext` instead. I've tried using `RelativeSource` but nothing I've tried so far works, and the more I look at the docs the more I feel it's designed for another job.

The XAML (with irrelevant details removed):

```xml
<Window x:Class="WPFQuestion.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFQuestion"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="930">
    <DockPanel>
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfA}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectionA}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <TabControl
            ItemsSource="{Binding SelectionA}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectionB}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Text="{Binding Path=???.SelectionBLogText}"/>
                        <Button Click="ClearLogButton_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code-behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    internal MainWindowViewModel vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
    // Various methods for event handling
}

public class A : IEnumerable<B>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B // previously : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LogText { get; set; }

    // various other properties
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private A _a;
    private B _b;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<A> ListOfA { get; set; }

    public A SelectionA
    {
        get => _a;
        set
        {
            if (_a == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _a = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectionA));
        }
    }

    public B SelectionB
    {
        get => _b;
        set
        {
            if (_b == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _b = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectionB));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectionBLogText));
        }
    }

    public string SelectionBLogText
    {
        get => SelectionB.LogText;
        set
        {
            if (SelectionB.LogText == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            SelectionB.LogText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectionBLogText));
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like this when you used relative binding? if not please check this out.

```
     <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
             Path=Datacontext.SelectionBLogText}"/>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't, I had `AncestorType=MainWindowViewModel`. It feels like such an obvious solution now that it's in front of me.